# "Cannot mix test roots with non-test roots"

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am trying to run instrumented tests for an Android app, but get this compile-time error:

```
Cannot mix test roots with non-test roots:
    Non-Test Roots: com.my.application.MyApplication
    Test Roots: [com.my.test.ActivityTest]
```

The application uses a custom app annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`, since the docs imply that this is required for Hilt.

My test follows this pattern:

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyTest {
  @Rule
  public HiltAndroidRule hiltRule = new HiltAndroidRule(this);

  @Inject
  SomeStuff stuff;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    hiltRule.inject();
  }
```

The app runner is creating a normal Hilt app:

```java
public class MyAppRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

  @Override
  public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
      throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(
            cl, HiltTestApplication.class.getName(), context);
```

When running a test, I get the compile-time error outlined above. I suppose that the reference to `MyApplication` comes from the app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I tried using a `@CustomTestApplication` with `MyApplication`, but custom test applications apparently don't work with applications annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`.

What is the proper way to set up a test with a Hilt-based application?

Answer (score 1):

To use the Hilt test application in instrumented tests, you need to configure a new test runner. This makes Hilt work for all of the instrumented tests in your project. Perform the following steps:

1. Create a custom class that extends AndroidJUnitRunner in the androidTest folder.
2. Override the newApplication function and pass in the name of the generated Hilt test application.

   class CustomTest : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

   ```
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
   ```

   }

Next, configure this test runner in your Gradle file as described in the instrumented unit test guide. Make sure you use the full classpath:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Replace com.example.android.dagger with your class path.
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.android.dagger.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}
```

Source : https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I already wrote in my question? I have this test runner set up, and I have confirmed that it's running.